# ¿Cuál es el problema de usar "publicar" o "publicación" en vez de "postear" o "post"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, significado, neologismos

En español tenemos dos palabras perfectamente válidas que pueden hacer las veces de "post" tanto en su versión como sustantivo como en su versión como verbo:

> **[publicación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UYSCFcN)**
>
> Del lat. publicatio, -ōnis.
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de publicar.
> 2. f. Escrito impreso, como un libro, una revista, un periódico, etc., que ha sido publicado.
>
> **[publicar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UYVs4Cj)**
>
> Del lat. publicāre.
>
> 1. tr. Hacer notorio o patente, por televisión, radio, periódicos o por otros medios, algo que se quiere hacer llegar a noticia de todos.
> 2. tr. Hacer patente y manifiesto al público algo. *Publicar la sentencia.*
> 3. tr. Revelar o decir lo que estaba secreto u oculto y se debía callar.
> 4. tr. Correr las amonestaciones para el matrimonio y las órdenes sagradas.
> 5. tr. Difundir por medio de la imprenta o de otro procedimiento cualquiera un escrito, una estampa, etc.

Sin embargo, cada vez que me tengo que referir a una publicación hecha en este sitio, aludiendo de forma genérica tanto a preguntas, como a respuestas e incluso comentarios, me sale solo el decir *un post* o incluso usar el verbo *postear*.

Viendo las definiciones del DLE, se echa en falta una específica sobre las nuevas tecnologías, como hace por ejemplo [el Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post):

> Post (verb) : to publish (something, such as a message) in an online forum (such as an electronic message board).
>
> Post (noun) : something (such as a message) that is published online.

Usos del verbo *postear* se pueden encontrar desde hace más de una década:

> *Recientemente he visto el interés de varios experimentados profesionales peruanos, residentes en esta área, por regresar al Perú y se me ocurrió sugerir a CARETAS que publique una sección de oportunidades laborales. Esta sección tendría alcance internacional en su edición de la Internet y ustedes podrían cobrar una tarifa a las empresas interesadas en 'postear' sus avisos.*
>
> Caretas, 13/06/1996 (Perú).

Y sigue hoy día, ya incluso sin el uso de las comillas para indicar el neologismo:

> *La credibilidad asignada a los diferentes tipos de "tweets" que se postean, es variada. Los twitteros institucionales tienen mayor credibilidad cuando se trata de actualización de información relevante; sin embargo, los twitteros individuales gozan de mayores seguidores dependiendo de su perfil.*
>
> Casas, María de la Luz: «Capítulo 2. TWITTER, ¿HERRAMIENTA PARA LA EXPRESIÓN PRIVADA, LA PARTICIPACIÓN PÚBLICA O LA CONSTRUCCIÓN DE ACUERDOS? LA PARTICIPACIÓN EN REDES SOCIALES DESDE LA TEORÍA DE LA ACCIÓN SOCIAL». Islas, Octavio; Ricaurte, Paola [coords.]: Investigar las redes sociales. Comunicación total en la sociedad de la ubicuidad. México, D. F.: Razón y Palabra, 2013.

Así pues, quería preguntar:

- ¿Está el uso de "postear" extendido sobre "publicar" cuando se habla de publicar artículos (mensajes, preguntas, respuestas, comentarios, etc.) en medios online en los países de habla hispana? Nota: en el diccionario de americanismos hay una entrada para *[postear](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=postear)* con otras acepciones además de la que se trata aquí.
- Si es así, ¿cuál es el motivo? ¿Acaso la palabra "publicar" está demasiado arraigada a las editoriales y medios impresos, y la gente que usa Internet ha encontrado en el neologismo *postear* la acepción que faltaba? La idea que tengo es que a menudo para "publicar" algo es necesaria la aprobación de un editor externo (frases como "me han publicado el artículo/libro/etc" no son raras), mientras que para *postear* no es necesario ese paso.
- ¿Existe alguna otra palabra en español (tal vez "mensaje") que pueda hacer las veces de "post" en su acepción de "publicación online"?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que "publicación" en el ámbito de la informática normalmente se usa con un [significado diferente](https://www.rayitasazules.com/publicaciones-digitales-que-son/).

Answer (score 2):

Buenas: En respuesta a tu primera pregunta, hay que tener en cuenta que muchos países latinoamericanos se han visto muy incluidos por el idioma inglés. Así, y como bien dices, en el diccionario de americanismos, aparece el término *postear*. En español, la palabra que yo usaría sería publicación, pero dado a la mayoría de personas latinoamericanas en el lenguaje español, nos hemos "acostumbrado" a muchos de los términos empleados allí.

En español, que yo conozca, no tenemos una palabra tan específica como publicación online, al menos que se use habitualmente. Si quiero usar sinónimos, podría usar *entrada*, o en menor medida, y no tan exactamente *comentario*. También usaría *mensaje*, como tú bien dices.

Espero que esto te haya resuelto la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Sobre la extensión del uso**

El sustantivo ***posteo*** y el verbo ***postear***, castellanizados del término ***post*** aparecen muy difundidos e incorporado de manera natural en la vida diaria. He oido  variantes y combinaciones (que hasta las entremezclan con publicación), como:

> "***postear***  un mensaje", "***publicar*** un ***post***, "***postear*** un tweet", etc

**2) Sobre los motivos**

sin duda hay un proceso de presión y asimilación en curso, con efectos idiomáticos sobre otras lenguas como producto de la [globalización](https://historialenguainglesa.blogspot.com/2013/01/the-spread-of-english-across-globe.html) y el establecimiento del inglés como l[ingua-franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_lingua_franca) (marcadamente en áreas tecnológicas, científicas y de cultura de masas), por lo que no es de extrañar que muchos términos específicos en el uso informático y de la web tiendan a prevalecer sobre sus equivalentes no-anglosajones.

**3) Acerca de otras alternativas en castellano (sobre cómo referirse a 'post' en tanto sustantivo)**

No veo ningun más apropiada que ***publicación***. El acto de ingresar información preparada para la lectura en medios digitales le cuadra bien a la definición de nuestra palabra, con las acepciones mencionadas:

> - ***Hacer notorio*** o patente, por televisión, radio, periódicos *o por otros medios*, ***algo que se quiere hacer llegar a noticia de todos***
> - ***Difundir*** por medio de la imprenta ***o de otro procedimiento cualquiera un escrito, una estampa, etc***.

Consecuentemente

> **el resultado material de la acción de** *hacer notorio* —por medios también digitales—, **o** *difundir un escrito* **debiera ser designado como  *publicación***

Answer (score 0):

Esto es una respuesta parcial -- no tengo respuesta para la tercera parte de tu pregunta.

Cuando pienso en la "publicación", imagino algo que pasó por un proceso más o menos riguroso de revisión; cuando pienso en un "post", pienso en algo que se ofreció quizás más a la ligera.  No sé si esto es objetivo, y francamente, en la época en que el español era mi idioma dominante, el uso del internet no había explotado todavía.

"Mensaje" desgraciadamente no me parece ideal como alternativa de "post" porque para mí "mensaje" es algo que se dirije a un individuo o a un grupo de individuos bien definidos, mientras que cuando algo se ofrece en el internet, la idea es hacer una difusión menos definida y más amplia.  Y se pierde todo control sobre el uso del texto.  Incluso se puede tergiversar y hasta deformar.